# Secure contents of a div which is centered on a page

Tags: html, css, centering

I am placing all my content into a section with a class="wrapper". This section has a set width and height and must satisfy the following conditions:

1. be placed in the middle of the page, both horizontally and vertically. If window size is larger than the `<section>` itself, then this element has to center itself automatically.
2. at the same time, if window size is smaller than the `<section>` size, the `<section>` should be entirely scrollable and all elements should be viewable.

I have a problem with part 2, since when I make the window size smaller, the upper and lower borders of the `<section>` actually disappear behind the screen and content. It appears that the top content is "eaten" by the vertical resizing. This does not happen with the left and right borders, I am still able to view full content by scrolling.

The described problem is true for Safari, Chrome and Opera, but not for Firefox. I have not tested in IE.

I use this to center vertically and horizontally:

```
.wrapper{
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: auto;  
    height: 660px;
    width: 1200px;
    border: 1px dotted yellow;
}
```

Obviously if I use the approach below then it does not work in Safari either, since `<section>` goes behind the viewport upon resizing:

```
.wrapper{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%; 
    margin-top: -330px; /* half of  height */
    margin-left: -600px;  /* half of width */
    height: 660px;
    width: 1200px;
    border: 1px dotted yellow;
}
```

Any advice on how to fit all content of the section will be appreciated!

Comment: can you give an example on jsfiddle or snippet

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/kemzkopm/1/  One can see that by resizing the result window, the width of the element is intact, but the height is eaten by window's upper border.

Comment: Are you looking for something like this : https://jsfiddle.net/kemzkopm/5/

Comment: @Ahmad Asjad  Well, this does not satisify condition 1 - where the section should be centered on the page BOTH horizontally and vertically.

Comment: Please find my answer for your solution

Answer (score 1):

https://jsfiddle.net/ahmadasjad/kemzkopm/13/

---

### HTML part:

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    <section class="wrapper">
        Wrapper Section
    </section>
  </div>    
</div>
```

---

### CSS part:

```
.wrapper{
    margin: 0 auto;  
    height: 100px;
    width: 400px;
    max-width:100%;
    border: 1px dotted red;

}
.child{
    vertical-align:middle;
    display:table-cell;
}
.parent{
    display:table;
    height:100vh;
    width:100%;
}
```